# execute last command in the history of that single command

Tags: shell, command

Say I just executed 'ls' , 'ls -l', 'cd ~', now how to execute 'ls -l', which is the last one in the history of the command ls.

Comment: You can just press the up arrow until you get to your command

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're in bash, type 'ls' then hit CTRL+r

that will recall last command with ls. hitting it again will recall the one before.

you can also use '!ls' to achieve the same thing.

alternatively you can use the history number an re-execute thus:

!23

if 'ls -l' was entry no. 23

but if you're looking for "run 2 commands ago". i'm not aware of anything, that's not to say there might not be something in another shell.

oops looks like someone already replied :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL+r and type some characters. You should get the last executed command staring with these characters.

Keep hitting CTRL+r to go back in history.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the last command you used ls -l then type: "!!" No quatations